# issue in query params in angular 8

Tags: angular, httprequest, http-parameters

I have a problem with the query parameters in angular 8. This is the code:

```
headers = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        })
    };

login(username, password) {

        console.log('login');

        let params = new HttpParams();
        params = params.append('username', username);
        params = params.append('password', password);
        let options = { headers: this.headers, params: params };

        return this.http.post<any>(this.host + 'login', options).pipe(map(data => {

                console.table(data);
                this.setSession(data);
                this.currentUserSubject.next(data.user);

            }));

    }
```

I also tried

```
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.set('username', username);
params = params.set('password', password);
```

and

```
let params = new HttpParams().set('username', username).set('password', password);
```

and

```
let params = new HttpParams().append('username', username).append('password', password);
```

The backend server get username and password as undefined, previously I had this code that worked correctly:

```
 login(username, password) {

    console.log('login');

    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/login?username='+username+'&password='+password, 
        {headers:{
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'}} 
    ).pipe(map(data => {

        this.setSession(data);
        this.currentUserSubject.next(data.user);

    }));

}
```

What's wrong? Thanks

Comment: There is no options variable in your first example? It looks like your backend takes the values from the query string - are you trying to set query string values via the options?

Comment: @KurtHamilton sorry I deleted some code from the post, I fix, now the post code is the same of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write it like this

```
const options = {headers: this.headers, params: {username, password}};
this.http.post<any>(this.host + 'login', null, options);
```

You need to change your headers object, there's no need for the HttpHeader wrapper around it

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
};
```

Btw: if your don't send a body maybe reevaluate the need for a post request

Comment: I added the headers

Comment: this seems a little confused, I would use options like in my code, is it possible?

Comment: the last parameter of the post IS the options object - extracted the options object like u have done

Comment: i get an error refering to 'options' in your suggest, 'No overload matches this call.'

Comment: Please add how your header object looks. just tested this and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You are posting the options as body. The third parameter of the `http.post` should be the options:

```
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('username', username);
params = params.append('password', password);

const options = { headers: this.headers, params: params };

return this.http.post<any>(this.host + 'login', null, options);
```

<sub>Why is this a post, if there is no body though? Wouldn't a GET make more sense?</sub>

Comment: thanks for reply, i get an error in your suggestion, 'No overload matches this call.'

Comment: @canerandagio sounds odd, but you can try to set the body to `null`

Comment: "Property 'user' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)" refering to 'this.currentUserSubject.next(data.user);'

Answer (score 0):

You should use http.get() method in case there is no body(i.e. you need to modify request method from post to get at backend).

```
 return this.http.get<any>(this.host + 'login', options).pipe(map(data => {

            console.table(data);
            this.setSession(data);
            this.currentUserSubject.next(data.user);

        }));
```

or if you want to use post method then use like (but its not a good practice.)

```
return this.http.post<any>(this.host + 'login', {},options).pipe(map(data => {

        console.table(data);
        this.setSession(data);
        this.currentUserSubject.next(data.user);

    }));
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i get an error in your suggestion, 'No overload matches this call.' refering to options.

Answer (score 0):

Try send js object after url. For exaple :

Let obj = {username:"username",password:"password"};

this.http.post("your url here",obj).subscribe(your arrow function here);

Good luck!